# Exclude field before creating a User from ModelForm? Django 4.1

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a user type patient that inherits from a custom user, I'm trying to delete the confirm password field from my data before creating the user object. The confirm password field isn't in the model but is made in the model form.
Im trying this code below but getting `got unexpected keyword arguments: 'confirm'`

**models.py:**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    object = UserManager()

class Patient(User):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Patients'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

**forms.py:**

```
class PateintForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    confirm = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    is_patient = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'email', 'password']

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'})
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm = cleaned_data.get("confirm")
        if confirm != password:
            self.add_error("password", "Passwords do not match.")
            self.add_error("confirm", "Passwords do not match.")
        if len(password) < 8:
            self.add_error("password", "Password must be greater than 8 letters.")
        if confirm == password and len(password) > 8:
            del cleaned_data['confirm']
            return cleaned_data
```

**views.py:**

```
def Patient(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PatientForm(request.POST, initial={'is_patient': True})
        if form.is_valid():
            Patient.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Login/')

        else:
            for field in form.errors:
                form[field].field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' is-invalid'
            return render(request, 'Home/RegPatient.html', {'form': form})
    
    else:
        form = PatientForm(initial={'is_patient': True})
        return render(request, 'Home/RegPatient.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.
If it does not delete the confirm password field, one just needs to:

```
del form.cleaned_data['confirm_pass')
```

before creating model object.